# On Premise Queue Options like Azure ServiceBus Queue

Tags: queue, message-queue

I have used Azure Service Bus queue in one of my previous projects. They are awesome. Features like FIFO, delivery guarantee, Blocking with / without timeout, Batch receive ... 
Currently I am designing an on premise solution. Looking for a similar queuing product ... doesn't have the appetite to go for a bigger product like Biztalk.

Answer (score 0):

Andy -- there is an on-premises version of Service Bus called Service Bus for Windows Server 1.1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn282144.aspx.

Regards,
Seth